# Can you enforce the same constraint on multiple generic type parameters?

Tags: c#, generics, constraints

I know you can you can do it like this:

```
void M<T1, T2, T3>() where T1 : S where T2 : S where T3 : S 
{}
```

I want something like this:

```
void M<T1, T2, T3>() where T1, T2, T3 : S 
{}
```

Is there any such shortcut?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that is not supported. The C# language spec states

> Each type-parameter-constraint-clause consists of the token where, followed by the name of a type parameter, followed by a colon and the list of constraints for that type parameter.

The key here is *a*, indicating that the grammer requires `where <TypeParam> : <Constraint1>,<Constraint2>, etc..` .